# create a string in PHP with methods to be executed after string is built

Tags: php

I am trying to run a loop to create a string that will be executed after it is built.  The string I am building looks like this:

```
        $createString = '$rb->create(';
        $createString .= '  $rb->logicalOr(';
        $createString .= '      $rb->logicalAnd(';
        $createString .= '          $rb["firstname"]->equalTo("mike"),';
        $createString .= '              $rb["lastname"]->equalTo("smith")';
        $createString .= '          ),';
        $createString .= '          $rb->logicalAnd(';
        $createString .= '              $rb["date_inserted"]->equalTo(02/11/2014),';
        $createString .= '              $rb["percent_completed"]->equalTo(1)';
        $createString .= '          )';
        $createString .= '   ),';
        $createString .= '    function() {';
        $createString .= '      echo "YAY";';
        $createString .= '  }';
        $createString .=');';

        $context = new Context(array(
             'firstname' => 'mike',
             ...
        ));

        $createString->execute($context);
```

However, when I run it I get the following error:

```
      Call to a member function execute() on a non-object
```

I hope someone can help guide me in the right direction.  Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: That will not work because variables will not be parsed under single quotes !

Comment: Right direction: you cannot call method on scalar variable ($createString is scalar variable, not object)

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran everything is okay with variables, try `$code = '$var = "some string";';
$code.= 'echo $var;';
eval($code);`

Comment: it's so CRAZY to use php code to generate string with php code, witch possibly can generate php variable

Comment: why you needed such type of php scipts into a php variable?

Comment: I am trying to build the string by running a loop through entries in a mysql table.  Once the string is built I need to execute the string.  I am open for any other suggestions of how to best go about doing this.

Answer (score 0):

you have php script in your `$createString` variable . You need to execute this script first.

You can try `eval()`.

try like this:

```
$createString = eval($createString);


$createString->execute($context);
```

Sample example:

```
$createString = "echo 123;";
echo "before eval: ". $createString."\n"; // it is eching php script output: echo 123;
$createString = eval($createString);
echo "after eval:". $createString; // it is echoing executed result of php script output: 123
```

[live demo](https://eval.in/112481)

Answer (score -1):

You've got your variables around the wrong way when calling `execute()`. I'm assuming this is what you are trying to do:

```
$context->execute($createString);
```